# Reading and parsing Thunderbird emails in Lua

Tags: lua, thunderbird

Is there a way to read and parse emails saved locally on Thunderbird using Lua or some library for Lua? I know I can use LuaSocket to send emails, but I'm unsure of how I can read the emails. In my roaming appdata for Thunderbird I see a file called All Mail which has the raw text containing the emails, but I don't know if there is an easier way to read that other than attempting to parse the 222k lines in that file.